# Accessing Oracle database from SQL Server stored procedure.

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, stored-procedures

I was wondering if someone could give me some pointers on how to connect to an Oracle Database from stored procedure in SQL Server.

Comment: One option is a [linked server to oracle](https://www.google.com/search?q=linked+server+to+oracle+from+sql+server+2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly on your SQL Server server you will need to install Oracle Client Tools, the reason behind this is any machine that wants access to a Oracle Database will need the necessary Oracle Client Tools installed to access it.

Secondly you will need to configure the file "**tnsnames.ora**" that is installed with the above configured to point to the required Oracle Server/Database that you want to connect to.

Now you will need to create a Linked Server from your SQL Server management studio for that server to the oracle server.

Then in your stored procedure you have to follow the rule of:
[SERVER_NAME].[DATABASE].[OWNER].[OBJECT] in order of accessing thing on the oracle database, but keep in mind this is SQL Server syntax and there might be some minor twiking needed.

This is a rough outline and I hope it has set you on your way.